# How to add Mobile button controls to html canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, touch-event

I'm working on a basic Canvas game with space invaders, everything is running except for mobile button controls. I can't find a way of including touch controls with how the keycodes are being used.

The working version can be found here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ymzBOJ

currently input is being handled like this:

```
handleInput: function() {
  if (isKeyDown(LEFT_KEY)) {
    this.xVel = -175;
  } else if (isKeyDown(RIGHT_KEY)) {
    this.xVel = 175;
  } else this.xVel = 0;

  if (wasKeyPressed(SHOOT_KEY)) {
    if (this.bulletDelayAccumulator > 0.5) {
      this.shoot();
      this.bulletDelayAccumulator`enter code here` = 0;
    }
  }
```